# select same value from N rows in a mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I m new to mysql and m trying to select N rows from a mysql table in eclipse. Now, i want to select N rows of same value from the database. I am using the following code

```
    User user= null;
    ArrayList<User> searchedUsers = new ArrayList<User>();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
            String authenticationSql;
            authenticationSql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE " + searchIn + " = ?";

            log.info(authenticationSql);
            stmt = (PreparedStatement) dbConn.prepareStatement(authenticationSql);
            stmt.setString(1, searchFor);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                user = new User(rs.getString("username"),
                        rs.getInt("user_type"), OnlineStatus.ONLINE);


                searchedUsers.add(user);                

            }


            rs.close();
            stmt.close();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            log.error("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
            log.error("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
            log.error("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
        }
```

The problem is this code only returns me the first value of the search and not the rest of the values are selected from the database. Can please some one point out what i m doing wrong here. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is the complete SQL statement prior to execution? Failing that, what is the value for `searchFor`.

Comment: The complete statement is something like this..
"SELECT * ,COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = ?"
searchFor is a string with the desired username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `count(*)` in statement like this.

It should give you some error like `Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause`

Comment: It gives the same output when i m not using count too.. why is it not giving me all the rows witht he same value.. any idea..

Comment: have you tried firing query directly in mysql browser or in mysql console ? what result it gives there ?

Comment: what is the query you fired directly in query browser ? i think there is some problem in your query syntax. what is "searchIn" ?

Comment: searchIn is a string here for the time being its username.. its the column name in the table.

Comment: what is the column name you want to match ? so you are passing that value too dynamically ?

Comment: its dynamic.. sometimes its username, sometimes its first_name, and sometimes its last_name

Comment: try passing this also in the preparedStatement manner like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE ? = ?" and then stmt.setString(1,searchIn) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the `COUNT(*)` from your `SELECT` that is grouping your results. Try without it

Comment: I tried without it too.. same result it only selects the first result and do not search for other with the same name.

Comment: have you tried running that query in a MySQL console and see how many results you get?

Comment: yes and i m getting all of the results. but on eclipse I am not getting more than one result..
total results are 3 on sql query and on eclipse its only 1..